# Python bar3d- How to change tick_label_format?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```py
ax.ticklabel_format(axis='z', style='sci', scilimits=(-2,2))
```

Gives error:

```
None
AttributeError: This method only works with the ScalarFormatter.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This works for me:

from matplotlib import ticker

formatter = ticker.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True)
formatter.set_scientific(True) 
formatter.set_powerlimits((-2,2))

ax.w_xaxis.set_ticklabels(column_names)
ax.w_yaxis.set_ticklabels(row_names)
ax.w_zaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```